# How to swap out MSMQ in NServiceBus 2.0 for a different transport technology

Tags: .net, nservicebus

What is the correct way to swap out MSMQ transport layer to leverage another transport technology under the hood from within the NServiceBus 2.0 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Andreas Ohlund](http://andreasohlund.blogspot.com) (@[andreasohlund](http://twitter.com/andreasohlund)) answered my question on twitter with the following:

"You should go for the NServiceBus trunk and implement IMessageQueue (see the Azure queue impl for reference)"

[NServiceBus trunk (CodeBetter TeamCity)](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html;jsessionid=3606FCEBD388904F21046D5312F2505E?buildTypeId=bt60&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv)

[Blog post by Andreas Ohlund on NServiceBus Azure transport layer implementation.](http://andreasohlund.blogspot.com/2009/11/nservicebus-on-azure-cloud.html)