# NServiceBus 2.0 considerations when running on Mono and deployed to *nix

Tags: linux, unix, mono, nservicebus

**Is NServiceBus compatible with Mono?
Are you / have you run NServiceBus on Mono? 
If so what issues did you run into?**

NServiceBus leverage's MSMQ by default.  I know this can be swapped out for different transport technologies, so I would imagine an initial task may involve implementing a provided *"IMessageQueue "* interface (or something along those lines) from the NServiceBus library that leverage's a cross platform or Unix Specific message queue / transport technology.

Related Question:
"[How to swap out MSMQ in NServiceBus 2.0 for a different transport technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092309/how-to-swap-out-msmq-in-nservicebus-2-0-for-a-different-transport-technology)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacob Lewallen has done work on NServiceBus under Mono using RabbitMQ (I think) - you can contact him via twitter at @jlewallen.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any actual coding with Mono, but I've been pondering message queue / mono related stuff myself lately.

Mono seems to implement `System.Messaging` using RabbitMQ under the hood ([Mono/System.Messaging](http://www.mono-project.com/SystemMessaging)), so I guess code that's written against the "normal" API should work.

There are some limitations to the implementation though, so I guess it depends on does NServiceBus use those features of MSMQ which Mono-folks weren't able to implement due to MSMQ's API not being generic enough.

Did you try this out, what approach did you take and did you run into any problems with it?