# What transport technology is a viable alternative to MSMQ on Unix based system?

Tags: unix, mono, nservicebus

I am planning on experimenting with NServiceBus on Mono to be deployed on Unix based systems.

NServiceBus leverage's MSMQ by default. This can be easilly swapped out for an alterntive transport technology.

**What I need to know is what are the alternatives to MSMQ on Unix based systems, and how to do they differ and what are the pros & cons?**

Related Questions:
"[How to swap out MSMQ in NServiceBus 2.0 for a different transport technolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092309/how-to-swap-out-msmq-in-nservicebus-2-0-for-a-different-transport-technology)y"
"[NServiceBus 2.0 considerations when running on Mono and deployed to Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092321/nservicebus-2-0-considerations-when-running-on-mono-and-deployed-to-unix)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [System.Messaging](http://www.mono-project.com/SystemMessaging)?

Comment: Good call! System.Messaging leverage's RabbitMQ (Mono.Messaging.RabbitMQ) but due to the .NET API structure being so closely tied to MSMQ it has not been an easy task for the Mono guys to translate to RabbitMQ, so the API is not 100% compatible. (but I never said it had to be)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know anything about NServiceBus or MSMQ, but I have looked some into using Apache ActiveMQ as a messaging service on Unix systems.  It looks like there is a C# version that works with Mono.  I'm not sure if this is what you want, but maybe it's worth a look?

http://activemq.apache.org/nms/nms.html

Answer (score 1):

ZeroMQ (http://www.zeromq.org/)

ZeroMQ .NET CLR & Mono binding (http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:clr)